# Missing type specifier despite correct namespace

Tags: c++, types, namespaces, directx, specifier

I'm getting an error I typically see if I forget to add on the `std::` to an object like `string`. In this case, its my own `namespace` called `x`. The specific errors are as follow:

`Error  59  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'  e:\cppworkspace\xengine\xengine\code\include\x\graphics\graphics.h  32  1   XEngine`

`Error  60  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\cppworkspace\xengine\xengine\code\include\x\graphics\graphics.h  32  1   XEngine`

The graphics header file:

```
#ifndef GRAPHICS_H
#define GRAPHICS_H

#include "x/x.h"
#include "x/graphics/d3dwrapper.h"

namespace x
{
    class Graphics
    {
    public:
        Graphics() {}
        ~Graphics(){}

        bool Init(int32 width, int32 height, bool fullscreen, HWND hwnd);
        void Destroy();
        void Update();
        void Render();
    protected:
    private:
        Graphics(const Graphics& other) {}

        D3DWrapper* m_d3d; // ERROR IS HERE
    };
}
#endif // GRAPHICS_H
```

The D3DWrapper header file:

```
#ifndef D3DWRAPPER_H
#define D3DWRAPPER_H

#include "x/x.h"
#include "x/system/system.h"

namespace x
{
    class D3DWrapper
    {
    public:
        D3DWrapper();
        ~D3DWrapper() {}

        bool Init(int32 width, int32 height, bool fullscreen, HWND hwnd);
        void Release();
        bool InitScene();

        void BeginScene(Color color);
        void EndScene();

        inline ID3D11Device* GetDevice() { return m_device; }
        inline ID3D11DeviceContext* GetDeviceContext() { return m_deviceContext; }

    protected:
    private:
        D3DWrapper(const D3DWrapper& other) {}

        ID3D11Device* m_device;
        ID3D11DeviceContext* m_deviceContext;
        IDXGISwapChain* m_swapChain;
        ID3D11RenderTargetView* m_renderTargetView;
    };
}


#endif // D3DWRAPPER_H
```

I cannot seem to figure out what could possibly be wrong with my code to get this error so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any includes inside x.h which possibly include one of the two files above? And is it on purpose that your (copy) constructors have an empty body?

Comment: Could you perhaps give us a clue as two which lines are generating those errors? That's why the error messages have line numbers.

Comment: @PeteBecker My mistake, I'll edit the question but its the `D3DWrapper* m_d3d` line in the graphics header

Comment: code seems to be correct. There shouldn't be any problem with the namespace. The only thing i noticed, is that you have a double include of x/x.h, because your D3DWrapper is already including it (maybe you hav no ifndef statement there)

Comment: @kaiser I removed the double include, but that didn't help. I'm starting to think its a problem some how with my system.h, as it includes the graphics which includes d3dwrapper? will try toying with that after classes